# Exchangeability does not imply independence: Example

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

My lecture notes mention that the following collection of random variables is exchangeable but not independent.

$ \epsilon_{i} = \eta_{i} + \sigma $

where $ \eta_{i}$ is i.i.d. across i and $\sigma$ is independent of $\eta_{i} \forall$ i.

From my understanding the $\sigma$ is just one realization that is maintained across all the collection of $\epsilon$'s. This introduces a dependence. The issue is, how do I prove that the sequence is exchangeable?

The definition is the following: A collection of random variables $\epsilon_{i}$ is exchangeable if for every finite subset of the random variables,$\epsilon_{i_{1}}, ..., \epsilon_{i_{n}}$ and for every permutation $\varphi$:

$\mu(\epsilon_{i_{1}} \leq a_{1}, \epsilon_{i_{2}} \leq a_{2},..., \epsilon_{i_{n}}\leq a_{n})= \mu(\epsilon_{\varphi (i_{1})} \leq a_{1}, \epsilon_{\varphi(i_{2})} \leq a_{2},..., \epsilon_{\varphi(i_{n})}\leq a_{n})$

This definition is really hard to work with and I don't even know how to introduce all the permutations posible in a proof.

One could start with one side:

$\mu(\epsilon_{i_{1}} \leq a_{1}, \epsilon_{i_{2}} \leq a_{2},..., \epsilon_{i_{n}}\leq a_{n})= \mu(\eta_{1} + \sigma \leq a_{1}, \eta_{2} + \sigma \leq a_{2},..., \eta_{n} + \sigma\leq a_{n})$

Bu then I am completely stuck...

Comment: It should be "obvious" that it's exchangeable. If not, consider the case $n=2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on Andrew's comment, start by considering a finite subset of the $\epsilon$, say $\epsilon_{i_1}, \epsilon_{i_2}, \ldots, \epsilon_{i_n}$. These can be written as $\eta_{i_1} + \sigma, \eta_{i_2} + \sigma, \ldots, \eta_{i_n} + \sigma$.

We then look at a permutation $\varphi$ of the indices $(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_n)$. The set after the permutation would be $\epsilon_{\varphi(i_1)}, \epsilon_{\varphi(i_2)}, \ldots, \epsilon_{\varphi(i_n)}$, which can be written as $\eta_{\varphi(i_1)} + \sigma, \eta_{\varphi(i_2)} + \sigma, \ldots, \eta_{\varphi(i_n)} + \sigma$, so that:
$$
\mu(\epsilon_{i_1} \leq a_1, \ldots, \epsilon_{i_n} \leq a_n) = \mu(\eta_{i_1} + \sigma \leq a_1, \ldots, \eta_{i_n} + \sigma \leq a_n).
$$
Due to the independence of the $\eta_i$ and $\sigma$, this joint distribution factors as follows:
$$
\mu(\eta_{i_1} \leq a_1 - \sigma, \ldots, \eta_{i_n} \leq a_n - \sigma) \times \mu(\sigma).
$$

Similarly, recalling the definition of exchangeability, we get:
$$
\mu(\epsilon_{\varphi(i_1)} \leq a_1, \ldots, \epsilon_{\varphi(i_n)} \leq a_n) = \mu(\eta_{\varphi(i_1)} + \sigma \leq a_1, \ldots, \eta_{\varphi(i_n)} + \sigma \leq a_n),
$$
which factors as:
$$
\mu(\eta_{\varphi(i_1)} \leq a_1 - \sigma, \ldots, \eta_{\varphi(i_n)} \leq a_n - \sigma) \times \mu(\sigma),
$$
and we are done.

Comment: Thank you @Ekene E. !!! This was very enlightening! Just to be clear about the proof: At the end when you indicate that we are done, the permutations do not make the joint cdf be different because the etas are i.i.d. i.e. which means that the order in which they appear doesn't matter? If we where to drop the identically distributed this would not be exchangeable? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The permutations do not affect the joint CD because $\eta_i$ are i.i.d., so the joint CDF remains the same under permutations of the indices. If the $\eta_i$ were independent but not i.i.d., then the permutations of the indices could have an enumeration of different joint distributions, which is not good for an exchangability proof. You're welcome!

Comment: @Fledermaus Feel free to accept the answer!

Comment: Didn't know about the existence of accepting the answer button! Thanks for that! @Ekene E.  I am still reviewing the proof and I have a last question if it wouldn't be too much asking: How comes one can factor the joint distribution like that? I am between two concepts: the definition of independence of two stochastic processes? Or are you using the concept of convulsion of sum of random variables?

Comment: The factorisation is a direct consequence  of the independence of the stochastic processes.